# YouTube Live Streaming API Limits

Tags: youtube, youtube-livestreaming-api

I need to create an application that will automatically publish multiple video streams on different youtube channels of my clients.

can I publish applications from one stream to different channels or one application - one channel?
can I concurrently publish several independent live events per channel? what are the restrictions on the number of concurrent events?

By default, for the YouTube Data API v3  i have 3,000.0 units/second/user Per-User Limit. What this means? Do I understand correctly, that every client will be able to see the live broadcast, that i created through this api is not more than 3'000 seconds?